# Test writing to file at the same time as anyone else using file_put_contents

Tags: php, io

I have a form on a page which after submitting its content is written to a file using file_put_contents.
I use LOCK_EX to lock the file while writing to it. But is there some way to try that this actually works and to see what happens when the file is called twice at the same time.

```
$answer = file_put_contents($file, $skier, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    if($answer != false){
      //I want to see if that works
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try by launching N bat/shell that will try to execute your PHP code at the same time and accessing the same file

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.

So to test it, you could:

1. open a file and lock it using `fopen()`;
2. lock the file using `flock()`;
3. write a line using `fwrite()`;
4. wait a few seconds using `sleep()`;
5. repeat the previous two steps a few time;
6. call this script from two browsers / computers / tabs at more or less the same time.